# How to load related entities in a fast way

Tags: c#, mysql, entity-framework, entity-framework-4, dbcontext

I'd like to load a `Test` by id including all related `TestRuns` and all `Measurements` using *DbContext*/*EntityFramework* from a MySql database.

This is the database schema:

[image]

What I tried so far:

```
public class TestRepository : Repository<Test>, ITestRepository
{
    public IQueryable<Test> GetTestComplete(int id)
    {
      return DbSet.Where(t => t.Id == id)
                  .Include(t => t.TestRuns.Select(tr => tr.Measurements));
    }
}
```

Unfortunately this takes a very long time to complete (about one minute for 1 Test/1 Testrun/15000 Measurements). I tried to understand the generated SQL code by using a query profiler, but couldn't make sense of the huge monster SQL statement.

**Can you think of a better (i.e. faster) way to load the data using DbContext?**

---

**Update**

Another try, also resulting in a looong loading time:

```
public Test GetTestComplete(int id)
{
    Test test = DbSet.Find(id);
    DbContext.Entry(test).Collection(t => t.TestRuns).Load();
    foreach (var testRun in test.TestRuns)
    {
        // next line takes a lot of time!
        DbContext.Entry(testRun).Collection(tr=>tr.Measurements).Load(); 
    }
    return test;
}
```

Loading the measurements takes 84% of the time:

[image]

This is the corresponding sql statement for fetching the measurements:

```
SELECT 
Extent1.id,
Extent1.test_run_id,
Extent1.rss_dbm
FROM measurement AS Extent1
WHERE Extent1.test_run_id = :EntityKeyValue1
```

I copied each of the resulting sql statements (from the three  `DbContext`/`DbSet` queries) from the query profiler into *MySqlWorkbench*, and each for itself is running very fast. Now I am even more confused...

---

**Update 2**

I isolated the function `GetTestComplete` (see above) in a single unit/performance test and it still takes a long time. The output of the query profiler shows that the individual sql commands are very fast, even though the whole test takes about 5 seconds to complete.
Confusion growing...

[image]

Comment: If you only want to read the data (not modify them) you could use `DbSet.AsNoTracking()`. I think a lot of time is consumed by the entity state manager and relationship fixup. If you have to modify data I think you should try to only fetch what you need to modify.

Comment: @GertArnold: You were correct: the `DbSet.AsNoTracking()` will do the trick and reduce query time of Measurements from 4 s to 400 ms. But how to use `AsNoTracking()` with that query `DbContext.Entry(testRun).Collection(tr => tr.Measurements).Load();`?

Comment: @GertArnold: Oh, and thanks for your first comment! I'll gladly accept it as an answer if you move it from comment to answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Executing a query is one thing. EF will do that very fast. Quite another thing is materializing entity objects, creating `DbEntityEntry` and relationship objects for the change tracker.

If you fetch entities by...

```
DbSet.AsNoTracking()
```

...creating these `DbEntityEntry`s is taken out of the process, which usually considerably increases performance.

If you apply `AsNoTracking`, you can only use `Include` to load related entities. A statement like...

```
DbContext.Entry(testRun).Collection(tr => tr.Measurements).Load();
```

...will fail, because there won't be an entry for `testRun` in the first place, *and* the `Load` method is the opposite of `AsNoTracking`, sort of, because it is designed to load *tracked* entities into a context without returning them.

Comment: How do I query one test by id including all testruns and all measurements? I tried `DbSet.AsNoTracking().Where(t => t.Id == id).Include(t => t.TestRuns.Select(tr => tr.Measurements)).SingleOrDefault()`, but this will cause a `EntityCommandExecutionException`.

Comment: Exception message `Lost connection to MySQL server during query`

Comment: OMG, that's probably MySQL-specific. I never see this happening with Sql Server. In Sql Server this is probably prevented by enabling "multiple active result sets", but AFAIK there's not anything like that in MySQL.

Answer (score -1):

http://msdn.microsoft.com/pl-pl/library/bb738708%28v=vs.110%29.aspx - try this, but I have no idea about performance

Comment: That's what I already do in my first example above (i.e. using `Include`).